# Best way to convert timeZone in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

I want to convert one time from one timezone to another.

Example:

Image that I have a first Time, like

```
t=....
puts t
 => Sun Aug 12 00:00:00 +0200 2012
```

I want to have the exact same hour, but in a different time zone.
I can do this:

```
mytimezone.local(t.year,t.month,t.day,t.hour,t.min)
=> Sun, 12 Aug 2012 00:00:00 BRT -03:00
```

So is there a way to accomplish the same things in a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `in_time_zone` method?

```
 > t = Time.parse("Sun Aug 12 00:00:00 +0200 2012")
 => 2012-08-12 02:00:00 +0400
 > t.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
 => Sat, 11 Aug 2012 18:00:00 EDT -04:00 
 > mytimezone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
 => (GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
 > t.in_time_zone(mytimezone)
 => Sat, 11 Aug 2012 18:00:00 EDT -04:00
```

Comment: in fact I want to do the "opposite" of in time zone: from your example, the expected result of hat I want to do would be:"Sat, 12 Aug 2012 02:00:00 EDT -04:00". In other word, I want the to convert midnight in one timezone to midnight in another time zone